# Laravel datatables searching belongsToMany name

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to search datatables by the `name` column of a table in a belongsToMany relationship. In this case, the table is `tags`.

Here are the tables in question:

```
Schema::create('leads', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('data');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('color');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('tag_lead', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('lead_id');
    $table->integer('tag_id');
});
```

Here is my model code:

```
class Lead extends \Eloquent
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
$leads = Lead::with('tags')->get();

return Datatables::of($leads)
    ->filterColumn('tags', function($query, $keyword) {
        $query->whereRaw('tags.name like ?', ['%'.$keyword.'%']);
    })
    ->make(true);
```

Here is my JS code:

```
$('#leads-datatable').DataTable({
    ajax: '{{ route('backend.leads.datatable') }}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'data' },
        { data: 'tags', sortable: false },
        { data: 'created_at' },
        { data: 'updated_at' }

    ]
});
```

This does not work and produces error `mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

I just want datatables to search all the tag names for each lead. How do I do this?

Comment: `'%'.$keyword.'%'` Try not to pass it as an array

Comment: What's the type of `$keyword`? string or array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply having to switch it from a collection to a query:

```
    $leads = Lead::with('tags')
        ->select('leads.*')
        ->leftJoin('lead_tag', 'lead_tag.lead_id', '=', 'leads.id')
        ->leftJoin('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'lead_tag.tag_id')
        ->groupBy('leads.id');

    $dt = Datatables::of($leads);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you are looking for all `leads` that have a `tag` name of `$keyword` variable? If that is the case, you just need to change your Controller code to:

```
$leads = Lead::whereHas('tags', function($q) use($keyword) {
  $q->where('name', '=', $keyword);
})
->with('tags')
->get();

return $leads;
```